# How to have a task scheduler script running as network service access a network share securely?

Tags: windows, powershell, task-scheduler

Goal is to have a task scheduler task activate a PowerShell script at a certain time.

We have had problems where the server restarts and the script doesn't run because I was not logged in as my domain account. I tried tying it to network service but my script needs to deposit CSV on a network share and network service can't access it.

I need to do this securely. I cannot run as highest privileges. The script needs to run if I am logged in or not, hence why I want to use the network service account.

I do not think this question has been asked before.

Looking at
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953861/access-windows-share-under-network-service-account/1953883#1953883

I see people mention here and other threads that you can get the network service to run as a domain user.

But I can't find the network service service in services.msc. I know you need to access log on and etc. Task scheduler service won't let you change the user it runs by.

But I still don't know what service to choose to make my task scheduler task running as network service run as a domain user with access to the share.

here are the pics, it didn't save :(

https://imgur.com/a/mqtlbsG

Comment: `can't find the network service service in services.msc` you need to include screen shots.

Comment: @GregAskew Providing now. I will revise.

Comment: Don't change the account that Task Scheduler logs on as, that doesn't accomplish anything.

Answer (score 1):

**A service that runs in the context of the NetworkService account presents the computer's credentials to remote servers.** ([NetworkService Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/networkservice-account))

That mean if you setup a task with the NETWORK SERVICE account, which will be added as another account in your printscreen, it would present the computer account to access the share.

If you give access to that share to that computer anyone accessing that server will have access to that share.

If you want a secure share, please use the task with a domain account done specificaly for that task. NetworkService is really limited, and depending of the task it do on your local computer, it might be blocked to do the task work.